# Gamma is consistent and complete if and only if there is exactly one truth assignment that satisfies Gamma

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $\Gamma$ be any set of formulas of P. Show that the following are equivalent:

(1) $\Gamma$ is consistent and complete.

(2) There is exactly one truth assignment that satisfies $\Gamma$

I have proved from (2) to (1).

But from (1) to (2), so far (1) can prove that for any truth assignment $\phi$, then $\phi(A)=T$. But how should we prove there is only one truth assignment?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. This question has been asked recently:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549262/showing-consistency-and-completeness-implies-a-unique-truth-assignment/
See if the answer I gave there helps you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing Consistency and Completeness implies a unique truth assignment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549262/showing-consistency-and-completeness-implies-a-unique-truth-assignment)

Comment: Yes! thank you!